# Backstage: build docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, backstage

I am trying to build a docker image of backstage code (https://github.com/backstage/backstage)
Also, my dockerfile is the same as what is documented here: https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/docker#multi-stage-build

However, whenever I try to build a docker image it complains of an error:

```
#19 [build 10/10] RUN yarn build
#19 sha256:230493e99704b51c04c3dfbb54c48c05c41decce3b8cac9992d7ce37b5211ea8
#19 1.208 yarn run v1.22.1
#19 1.257 $ backstage-cli repo build --all
#19 1.272 /bin/sh: 1: backstage-cli: not found
#19 1.287 error Command failed with exit code 127.
#19 1.287 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
#19 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn build]: exit code: 127
```

Could someone please help with what I am missing here while building the docker image?

Thank-you!

Comment: Can you paste a copy of your `package.json` here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS packages

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY packages packages
COPY catalog-info.yaml ./

#COPY plugins plugins

RUN find packages \! -name "package.json" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec rm -rf {} \+

# Stage 2 - Install dependencies and build packages

FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=packages /app .

# install sqlite3 dependencies 

#RUN apt-get update && \
#    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev python3 build-essential && \
#    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 600000 && rm -rf "$(yarn cache dir)"

COPY . .

RUN yarn tsc
RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend build

# If you have not yet migrated to package roles, use the following command instead:
#RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend backstage-cli backend:bundle --build-dependencies

# Stage 3 - Build the actual backend image and install production dependencies
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim

WORKDIR /app

# install sqlite3 dependencies, you can skip this if you don't use sqlite3 in the image
#RUN apt-get update && \
#    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev python3 build-essential && \
#    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
#    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

# Copy the install dependencies from the build stage and context
COPY --from=build /app/yarn.lock /app/package.json /app/packages/backend/dist/skeleton.tar.gz ./
RUN tar xzf skeleton.tar.gz && rm skeleton.tar.gz

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 600000 && rm -rf "$(yarn cache dir)"

# Copy the built packages from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/packages/backend/dist/bundle.tar.gz .
RUN tar xzf bundle.tar.gz && rm bundle.tar.gz

# Copy any other files that we need at runtime
COPY app-config.yaml ./
#COPY github-app-proficloud-backstage-app-credentials.yaml ./ 

#This is for Tech-Docs
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
#RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.0.1

#This is enable for software templating to work
#RUN pip3 install cookiecutter

CMD ["node", "packages/backend", "--config", "app-config.yaml"]
```

Comment: I am not installing Sqlite3 dependencies because I have configured postgres DB, may be in your case it should required.